# Java: Специальные символы

Tags: java, replace

Как с помощью метода [`.replaceAll("\[", "")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) можно заменить `[` на специальный символ `\u00A7` (означает символ `&`)?

Как будет выглядеть `[` в этой записи?

Comment: в​р​​​​​о​​​​​​д​е `\\[`

Comment: @diraria Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Экранирование служебных символов в регулярных выражениях осуществляется добавлением `\` перед экранируемым символом.

Но так как `\` имеет [особый смысл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) в Java-строках (например `\t` означает символ табуляции, `\n` означает символ перевода строки), то при записи строки в исходном коде программы символ `\` нужно экранировать, используя тот же `\`. Получится `\\`.

---

Таким образом строка с регулярным выражением, описывающим символ `[` выглядит так:

```
"\\["
```

---

А, например, строка с регулярным выражением, описывающим символ `\` выглядит так:

```
"\\\\"
```

Здесь после связанного с Java-строками экранирования получится строка `\\`, которая является регулярным выражением для символа `\`.